# How to override a property of a base class with an incompatible type?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-class

I have this declared class in some third party library that I can't modify:

```
export declare class KeyboardSensor implements SensorInstance {
  private props;
  constructor(props: KeyboardSensorProps);
  private attach;
  private handleStart;
  private detach;
  static activators: {
      eventName: "onKeyDown";
      handler: (event: React.KeyboardEvent, { keyboardCodes, onActivation, }: KeyboardSensorOptions) => boolean;
  }[];
}
```

And I want to customize it in this way with new class extending from that declaration:

```js
export class CustomKeyboardSensor extends KeyboardSensor {
  public static activators = [
    {
      eventName: "onKeyDown" as const,
      moreCode: "...",
    },
    {
      eventName: "onKeyUp" as const,
      moreCode: "...",
    },
  ];
}
```

I am obviously getting an error that the type property is incompatible:

> Types of property 'eventName' are incompatible.

How can I define new interface/type for the declare class where I can modify the `eventName` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Class inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-heritage) in TypeScript does not allow derived classes to be *broader* than base classes. As per the Handbook:

> TypeScript enforces that a derived class is always a subtype of its base class.

This means that members of the class that `extends` the base class that you override are [*covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) (as derived class is always a *subclass* of its base or, put simply, is *more specific*). Consider the following - the override works because `"A"` is a subtype of a broader union `"A" | "B"`:

```js
class A {
    static b : Array<{ c: "A" | "B" }> = []
}

class B extends A {
    static b : Array<{ c: "A" }> = [] // OK
}
```

However, the opposite results in an assignability error because the overridden members *are not* contravariant:

```js
class C {
    static b : Array<{ c: "C" }> = []
}

class D extends C {
    static b : Array<{ c: "C" | "D" }> = [] // Type '"D"' is not assignable to type '"C"'
}
```

The latter example is semantically equivalent to your case: `eventName` is declared to be a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `onKeyDown`, meaning any and all extending classes are not allowed broaden it, hence the error.

---

Your options are limited, however, there is a hacky way to go around that. Suppose you have the following base class `E`:

```js
class E {
    constructor(public e : string) {}
    static b : Array<{ c: "E" }> = []
    static s : number = 42;
}
```

First, let's declare the derived class and name it somehow, let it be `FB`:

```js
class FB extends E {
    constructor(public f: number) {
        super(f.toString());
    }
}
```

Pretty simple so far, right? Here comes the juicy part:

```js
const F: Omit<typeof FB,"b"> & { 
    new (...args:ConstructorParameters<typeof FB>): InstanceType<typeof FB> 
    b: Array<{ c: "E" | "D" }>
} = FB;
```

There is a lot to unpack. By assigning the declared derived class to a variable, we create a [class expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-expressions) `const F = FB;` which enables the *static* part of the class to be typed via explicit typing of the `F` variable. Now for the type itself<sup>0</sup>:

- `Omit<typeof FB, "b">` ensures the compiler knows the static side of `FB` (and, consequently, the base class `E`) is present except for the member `b` which we will be redefining later.
- `new (...args:ConstructorParameters<typeof FB>): InstanceType<typeof FB>` reminds the compiler that `F` is a constructor, whereas `args:ConstructorParameters` and `InstanceType` utilities free us to change the base class without the need to update the derived constructor type.
- `b: ...` readds the omitted `b` member to the static side of the derived class while broadening it (note that as class inheritance is not involved, there is no error).

All the above fixes the `b` member during compile-time, but we still need to make sure the static member is available at runtime with something like this (see MDN on [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) / [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for details):

```js
const descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(E, "b")!;
Object.defineProperty(F, "b", { 
    ...descr, 
    value: [...descr.value, { c: "D" }] 
});
```

Finally, let's check if everything works as expected:

```js
console.log(
    new F(42), // FB
    new F(42).e, // string
    F.b, // { c: "E" | "D"; }[]
    F.s // number
);

// at runtime:
// FB: {
//   "e": "42",
//   "f": 42
// },
// "42",  
// [{ "c": "D" }],  
// 42
```

---

Playground [with examples above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oQC5iwS2GgCNoAuOAJwrAE8AeBaYcgIlhegB9oWAhDgL4A%20aAF5oAbQC6qAalShIMXtACmADyyqAdgBMY8ZGgzZcBYmUrV6jZj3bRhYyVOgB6N9ADyAaVnyURShoAGFEVAxMHHxCEnJYKloGJlYQwRFxaX8UBXBggBE1TR19UPDjdFMYi3jEmxSeNK4efPTnaXdPABUaAAdVaAByFlbB6DwYbQB7LGglPABzbTAiEAGsKegsPoHhtMHs3KVoAFFyyOAp7WwKAFdgDYoACl7b1fMB8hu8bQWASkQcgqUTMsUsCWsyTsLBObUyMmBVXMMHI2luAFsiKoKM4ACwAJgA3IdAnkYAAxFQaLR6GBnIwXK43e6PF5vEDmABmqIxWIoAIZkRMt36z05ADoNgBlLAUH4LJ5-P7E4FAoGXa6zcnkLzovBYOjbfpTTnQSkAGhYRBYIgAZIhoBEMNpVAB3aBPcVesAUBYQUghJmyllTCgABR9YHRqi0FAghp2JrNvCEf3IAElNWBtMBVD1%20gnjabKUInegiLVIbZWLDmiN0rJnJSVRrsNBdKoIMAceIvEQAFaqB7ihYxryu7RhihTUXbfKd7t4Xqsk7mnjWv4AQhVfcHw47nJ%20qinM%20x2ye5LXVpYa8YXvFHa7FDXADcwCBbqpyBJ74-u%20K3w-VRbwaetHFcARlQCVspjWcUQCmBUy2gF13XJJ4CT%20NcPGTZDULNDD8T%20cVgM6KI5V%20ZDyXFIhsM8aseFrbh60JRwsmBaiYBwtFMWxVAoJyFAcNwaA7m0fBo1IVAcMpcgjBw9AWFUFhWAJG9pM8RTORU6ACQ0xxzX0lg1LXR0hM8CRGBYYAdLAgQpFM-SCWgIA) | [applied to your case](https://tsplay.dev/NnQvkw)

---

<sup>0</sup> Note that we often have to use the `typeof FB` type query — if we haven't declared the class earlier and opted to shortcut to `const F: {  ... } = class ...`, we would not be able to refer to the class itself when explicitly typing the variable (if we tried, the compiler would complain of a circular reference).

Comment: this is super useful to me, thanks for taking the time to describe it so cohesively!

Comment: @Petr not at all! Pretty nice challenge to work around the, albeit by-design, limitation :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't happy because here you've said that it can only be `onKeyDown`:

```
      eventName: "onKeyDown";
```

It should probably be just `string`:

```
      eventName: string;
```

And if you want it to always start with `on`, you can even do that, too:

```
      eventName: `on${string}`;
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified a little bit the description. The declare class is from third party library and I don't have access so I would prefer to create new interface extending from that and modifying it.. and I didn't figure out how.

Comment: I think that means they don't want you to extend it; all its members are private, too.